Getting PlatformException and
I am working on a project where I want to schedule a notification at a specific time. I have wrote the following code to acheive it but getting multiple platform exception. Since I am newbie I cannot understand what does this error says and what could be the solution of these exception. please don't just provide me with a solution also explain a little bit about the exception and what exactly I am doing wrong. I am using these packages: flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.0 and flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1 Thanks
When Application is started/launched:
E/flutter ( 7984): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalid_icon, The resource flutter_logo could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null, null)
E/flutter ( 7984): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
E/flutter ( 7984): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
E/flutter ( 7984): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7984): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:142:12)
E/flutter ( 7984): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7984): #3      NotificationService.initNotification (package:agriplus/Screens/Schedule%20Notification/notificationService.dart:23:5)
E/flutter ( 7984): <asynchronous suspension>

When pressing schedule notification button after selecting time:
E/flutter ( 7984): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exact_alarms_not_permitted, Exact alarms are not permitted, null, null)
E/flutter ( 7984): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
E/flutter ( 7984): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
E/flutter ( 7984): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7984): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:191:5)
E/flutter ( 7984): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7984): #3      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:352:7)
E/flutter ( 7984): <asynchronous suspension>

Relevant Code:
Using following permissions in AndroidManifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />

<queries>
    <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your application checks for inAppBrowserView launch mode support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
</queries>

Main Class:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initNotification();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => LanguageController(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<LanguageController>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) {
          if (locale.isEmpty) {
            provider.changeLanguage(
              const Locale('en'),
            );
          }
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'AgriPlus',
            locale: locale == ''
                ? const Locale('en')
                : provider.appLocale ?? Locale(locale),
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              AppLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate, //For IOS
            ],
            supportedLocales: const [
              Locale('en'),
              Locale('ur'),
            ],
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Inter',
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
                seedColor: const Color(0XFF00B251),
              ),
              useMaterial3: true,
            ),
            home: const DateTimePicker(),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

NotificationService Code:
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import '../../Reusable Widgets/motionToast.dart';

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('flutter_logo');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
            importance: Importance.max),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }

  Future scheduleNotification(
      {int id = 0,
        String? title,
        String? body,
        String? payLoad,
        required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduledNotificationDateTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        await notificationDetails(),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
}

Frontend Code:
Date Picker Class
import 'package:agriplus/Reusable%20Widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
import 'notificationService.dart';

class _DateTimePickerState extends State<DateTimePicker> {
  DateTime scheduleTime = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
                  context,
                  showTitleActions: true,
                  onChanged: (date) => scheduleTime = date,
                  onConfirm: (date) {},
                );
              },
              child: Text(
                'Select Date Time',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0XFF00B251),
                  fontFamily: 'Inter',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: size.width * 0.04,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            buildButton(
              'Schedule Notification',
              context,
              () {
                debugPrint('Notification Scheduled for $scheduleTime');
                NotificationService().scheduleNotification(
                    title: 'Scheduled Notification',
                    body: '$scheduleTime',
                    scheduledNotificationDateTime: scheduleTime);
              },
              size,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Check out => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309215/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionexact-alarms-not-permitted-exact-alarms

As for the first error make sure your logo file path and name is supplied correctly.
